# I´m not able to validate multi step form with Yup on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, yup

I´m creating a multi steps form on React. The steps are ok. I need to get it ready to backend, so I´m trying to use async function to validate de inputs.

This is my project structure:

- Signup (base code);
- Initial (step 1 - the user select "Pessoa Fisica" (natural person) or "Pessoa Juridica" (legal person);
- Pessoa Fisica (step 2 - If ok, go to step 4);
- Pessoa Juridica (step 3 - If ok, go to step 4);
- Success (step 4).

I´m trying to validate the step 2 first.

The base code of steps (Signup) is the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Initial from './_initial';
import PessoaFisica from './_pessoafisica';
import PessoaJuridica from './_pessoajuridica';
import Success from './_sucess';

export default class Signup extends Component {

    state = {
        step: 1,
        email: '',
        cpf: '',
        cnpj: '',
        datanascimento: '',
        acceptterms: '',
        acceptimage: '',
    };

    // go back to previous step
    prevStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState( { step: step - 1 } );
    };

    superprevStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState( { step: step - 2 } );
    };

    // proceed to the next step
    nextStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState( { step: step + 1 } );
    };

    supernextStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState( { step: step + 2 } );
    };

    // Handle fields change
    handleChange = input => e => {
        this.setState( { [ input ]: e.target.value } );
    };

    render() {
        const { step } = this.state;
        const { email, cpf, cnpj, datanascimento, acceptterms, acceptimage } = this.state;
        const values = { email, cpf, cnpj, datanascimento, acceptterms, acceptimage };

        switch ( step ) {
            case 1:
                return (
                    <Initial
                        nextStep={ this.nextStep }
                        supernextStep={ this.supernextStep }
                    />
                );
            case 2:
                return (
                    <PessoaFisica
                        prevStep={ this.prevStep }
                        supernextStep={ this.supernextStep }
                        handleChange={ this.handleChange }
                        values={ values }
                    />
                );
            case 3:
                return (

                    <PessoaJuridica
                        superprevStep={ this.superprevStep }
                        nextStep={ this.nextStep }
                        handleChange={ this.handleChange }
                        values={ values }
                    />

                );
            case 4:
                return ( <Success />

                );
            default:
            
        }
    }
}
```

The second step:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import * as Yup from "yup";


const PessoaFisica = ( { prevStep, supernextStep, handleChange, values } ) => {


    const Continue = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        supernextStep();
    };

    const Previous = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        prevStep();
    };

    const [ emailForm, setEmailForm ] = useState();
    const [ cpfForm, setCpfForm ] = useState();
    const [ birthday, setBirthday ] = useState();
    const [ termsAccepted, setTermsAccepted ] = useState();

    const [ checkboxStatus, setCheckboxStatus ] = useState( true );

    function buttonHandler() {
        setCheckboxStatus( !checkboxStatus );
    }



    function SubmitButton() {
        if ( emailForm && cpfForm && birthday && termsAccepted ) {
            return <button type="submit" disabled={ checkboxStatus } className="" onClick={ addUser }>Continuar</button>;
        } else {
            return <button type="submit" disabled className="">Continuar</button>;
        };
    };
        
    
    const addUser = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ( !( await validate() ) ) return;

        const saveDataForm = true;

        if ( saveDataForm ) {
            Continue;

        } else {
            setStatus( {
                type: 'error',
                mensagem: "Erro: Verifique os valores digitados e tente novamente!"
            } );
        }
    };

    async function validate() {
        let schema = Yup.object().shape( {
            cpf: Yup
                .string()
                .min( 11, ( { min } ) => `CPF deve conter no mínimo ${ min } caracteres` )
                .required( 'CPF é obrigatório' ),
            email: Yup
                .string()
                .email( "Por favor entre com um email válido" )
                .required( 'Email é obrigatório' ),
            datanascimento: Yup
                .string()
                .required( 'A data de nascimento é obrigatória. Você deve ser maior de 18 anos.' ),
             .test( "DOB",
                "error message",
                value => {
                    return moment().diff( moment( value ), 'years' ) >= 18;
                } ) 
        } );

        try {
            await schema.validate( values );
            return true;
        } catch ( err ) {
            setStatus( {
                type: 'error',
                mensagem: err.errors
            } );
            return false;
        }
    }

       
    return (
        <>
            //The inputs:

                        <label htmlFor="email" className="">E-mail</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" width="300" autoComplete="email" className="" onChange={ e => { handleChange( 'email' ); setEmailForm( e.target.value );  } } defaultValue={ values.email } required />

                        <label htmlFor="cpf" className="text-[16px] poppins mt-[24px] mb-[8px] text-black">CPF</label>
                        <input type="text" autoComplete="cpf" name="cpf" id="cpf" width="300" className="" onChange={ e => { handleChange( 'cpf' ); setCpfForm( e.target.value ); } } defaultValue={ values.cpf } required />

                        <label htmlFor="datanascimento" className="">Data de nascimento</label>
                        <input type="text" name="datanascimento" autoComplete="birthday" id="datanascimento" width="300" className="" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" onChange={ e => { handleChange( 'datanascimento' ); setBirthday( e.target.value );  } } defaultValue={ values.datanascimento } required />


                        //Other info here

                        //error message
                        { status.type === 'error' ? <p className="">{ status.mensagem }</p> : null }

                        <SubmitButton />

                        //other info below
    );
};
export default PessoaFisica;
```

But when I click the submit Button, it seems Yup don´t get the values. It throws a error message that the inputs are required, even when they aren´t empty. I need it to validate and then go to step 4.

**EDIT**

I changed everything. I ended up using Formik and material ui to validate Form. I changed the Signup file and everything is all right:

Signup.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Initial from './_initial';
import PessoaFisica from './_pessoafisica';
import PessoaJuridica from './_pessoajuridica';
import Success from './_sucess';

export default class Signup extends Component {

    state = {
        step: 1,
    };

    // go back to previous step
    prevStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState( { step: step - 1 } );
    };

    superprevStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState( { step: step - 2 } );
    };

    // proceed to the next step
    nextStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState( { step: step + 1 } );
    };

    supernextStep = () => {
        const { step } = this.state;
        this.setState( { step: step + 2 } );
    };

    render() {
        const { step } = this.state;

        switch ( step ) {
            case 1:
                return (
                    <Initial
                        nextStep={ this.nextStep }
                        supernextStep={ this.supernextStep }
                    />
                );
            case 2:
                return (
                    <PessoaFisica
                        prevStep={ this.prevStep }
                        supernextStep={ this.supernextStep }
                    />
                );
            case 3:
                return (

                    <PessoaJuridica
                        superprevStep={ this.superprevStep }
                        nextStep={ this.nextStep }
                    />

                );
            case 4:
                return ( <Success />

                );
            default:
           
        }
    }
}
```

I´m using the Signup just do control steps.

The second step:

```
import React from "react";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import { TextField, Button } from "@mui/material";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { validateCPF } from "validations-br";
import { Form, Formik, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import { parse } from "date-fns";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";


const PessoaFisica = ( { prevStep, supernextStep } ) => {
    const Previous = ( e ) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        prevStep();
    };

    const validationSchema = yup.object( {
        cpf: yup
            .string()
            .transform( ( value ) => value.replace( /[^\d]/g, "" ) )
            .min( 11, " O CPF deve conter no mínimo 11 caracteres" )
            .test( "is-cpf", "O CPF não é válido", ( value ) => validateCPF( value ) )
            .required( "O CPF é obrigatório" ),
        email: yup
            .string()
            .email( "Por favor entre com um email válido" )
            .required( "Email é obrigatório" ),
        datanascimento: yup
            .date()
            .transform( ( value, originalValue, context ) => {
                // check to see if the previous transform already parsed the date
                if ( context.isType( value ) ) return value;

                // Date parsing failed in previous transform
                // Parse the date as a euro formatted date string or returns Invalid Date
                return parse( originalValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", new Date() );
            } )
            .max(
                new Date( Date.now() - 567648000000 ),
                "Você precisa ter pelo menos 18 anos"
            )
            .required( "A data de nascimento é obrigatória" )
            .typeError( "Digite uma data válida" ),

        acceptterms: yup
            .boolean()
            .oneOf( [ true ], "Você precisa aceitar nossos Termos e Condições" ),
    } );

    return (
        <>
    //(...)
    <Formik
                        validationSchema={ validationSchema }
                        validateOnMount
                        initialValues={ {
                            tipodepessoa: "Pessoa Física",
                            email: "",
                            cpf: "",
                            datanascimento: "",
                            acceptterms: false,
                            acceptimage: false,
                        } }
                        onSubmit={ ( values ) => {
                            alert( JSON.stringify( values, null, 2 ) );
                            supernextStep();
                        } }
                    >
                        { ( formik ) => (
                            <Form
                                className="w-full h-full justify-between flex flex-col p-[30px_32px_16px] lg:p-[35px_32px_16px] box-border"
                                action=""
                                method="post"
                                onSubmit={ formik.handleSubmit }
                            >
    //...
    <TextField
                                        name="email"
                                        id="email"
                                        width="300"
                                        label="E-mail*"
                                        placeholder="Digite um e-mail válido"
                                        autoComplete="email"
                                        onChange={ formik.handleChange }
                                        value={ formik.values.email }
                                        error={ formik.touched.email && Boolean( formik.errors.email ) }
                                        helperText={ formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email }
                                    />
```

And so go on...